# Stop event listening after route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In one of my components I listen to keyboard events, with some keys triggering certain behaviors.

However, once the route changes and user navigates to another component, I no longer want to react to keyboard events. Is the only way to achieve that to move my event listener to a higher order component and conditionally react to or discard events based on the current active route?

Here is my highest order component:

```
class AppRouter extends Router {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Explorer</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/charts">Charts</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <hr/>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Viewer}/>
          <Route path="/charts" component={Charts}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppRouter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my event listener, found in the Viewer component but that I don't want active anywhere else:

```
  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.which === 37)
      return this.fetchSibling('next');
    if (e.which === 39)
      return this.fetchSibling('previous');
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: Which version of react-router?

Comment: Some example code pared down to show only the problem would also help.

Comment: React Router v4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found consists in removing the event listener before unmounting the component. However, to do that I need to keep a reference to the event handler, that also properly binds `this` to it. Here is the code I used:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({listener: this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}, () => document.addEventListener('keydown', this.state.listener));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.state.listener);
    this.setState({listener: null});
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped greatly!